# Rcpp Modules to Expose Class (Error: loadModule not found)

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am having trouble with setting up my package environment to expose cpp class to R as S4 method. I am trying to use Rcpp Modules. My class also uses RcppArmadillo. I created my initial package environment in RStudio as "Create package with RcppArmadillo" command.

So far, I have followed the guidelines from the official Rcpp modules vignette and the example provided here (https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-modules-bank-account).

Here is my **file set up** (I added comments to the files I actually added by hand):

```
├── DESCRIPTION // generated by default (added some things by hand)
├── NAMESPACE // generated with Roxygen
├── R
│   ├── RcppExports.R 
│   ├── exportClass.R // exporting the class with loadModule
│   └── exportPackage.R // setting up package environment with Roxygen
├── Read-and-delete-me
├── man
│   ├── rModulesArmaTest-package.Rd
│   └── rcpparma_hello_world.Rd
├── rModulesArmaTest.Rproj
└── src
    ├── Makevars
    ├── Makevars.win
    ├── RcppExports.cpp
    ├── RcppExports.o
    ├── class.cpp // class realization
    ├── class.h // class structure
    ├── class.o
    ├── module.cpp // exporting with Rcpp modules
    ├── module.o
    ├── rModulesArmaTest.so
    ├── rcpparma_hello_world.cpp
    └── rcpparma_hello_world.o
```

Here is the code inside:

**Description**:

```
Package: rModulesArmaTest 
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Date: 2020-11-17
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.5), methods
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
SystemRequirements: C++11
```

**NAMESPACE**

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
```

**class.cpp**

```
#include "class.h"

int Tree::getId() {
  return this->_id;
}

arma::mat Tree::add(const arma::mat& A, const arma::mat& B) {
  return (A + B);
}
```

**class.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

class Tree {
public:
  Tree(int id): _id(id) {}
  int getId();
  arma::mat add(const arma::mat& A, const arma::mat& B);
private:
  int _id;
};
```

**module.cpp**

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
#include "class.h"
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

RCPP_MODULE(RcppArmaEx){
  Rcpp::class_<Tree>("Tree")
  .constructor<int>()
  .method("add", &Tree::add)
  .method("getId", &Tree::getId);
}
```

**exportClass**

```
# Export the "BankAccount" C++ class by explicitly requesting BankAccount be
# exported via roxygen2's export tag.
#' @export Tree

loadModule(module = "RcppArmaEx", TRUE)
```

**exportPackage**

```
#' @useDynLib RcppArma, .registration = TRUE
#' @import methods Rcpp
"_PACKAGE"
```

The specific **error** I get is:

```
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadModule(module = "RcppArmaEx", TRUE) : 
  could not find function "loadModule"
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘rModulesArmaTest’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rModulesArmaTest’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rModulesArmaTest’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rModulesArmaTest’

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Do we have existence proofs of packages using `Rcpp::S4` with Rcpp Modules?  I cannot right now think of an example package.  So if what you have right now blows up and fails I suggest simplifying.  Maybe start with a minimal Modules packages, then add Armadillo, and so on.  The generators are not tested for all possible permutations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I was trying to start from the simplest possible example of BankAccount outlined in https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-modules-bank-account. When I directly clone the package, it seems to work just fine. However, as so as I start changing the name of the class to something else everything breaks down. I have tried to use the instructions there in this repo to set up the package from scratch, but this also does not seem to work.

Comment: You are doing too much at once.  The empty `NAMESPACE` file is wrong and in conflict with what the Rcpp Modules docs tell you---so far a starter do not run `roxygenize()` or at least tell it to leave the `NAMESPACE` file alone.

Comment: Great! Thank you!  I kept playing with the minimal example and got it working by removing Roxygen for once and manually setting up the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: I should have clicked sooner on that, 'function not found' for `loadModule` was a strong hint that something simple was amiss at the setup.